# Why Domain is Loading very slowly but when opening directly through App Engine Url it is opening very fastly?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Domain which i bought it from `GoDaddy.com` and i have linked it to `Google App Engine Flexible(NodeJs) Environment`.

Now I when I am opening my Domain then it is sometimes taking more than `5 secs` to load and sometimes I am getting `Error`

> Server Error - 502

But the thing is when i am directly opening my app engine url which is `https://************.appspot.com/` then it is always opening without `status code 502` and also `very fast`.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem got solved when i deployed my App again on different `region` (`asia-south1`) previously it was deployed on region `us-east1`. Don't know what was the error but it worked for me.